Vernam with multiple shorter (space) key per encryption
I have the following question, what if I have a message composed of $N$ bytes that as any byte can have value in a space of $[0-255]$ covering the full domain of those bytes.
Then have 2 keys both random and long as the message (so key length is $N$) but composed by symbols with a space that is half of message byte space (so $[0-127]$).
I know the thing to do is compose back the two keys in one single key with the same space of the message (so $[0-255]$).
My question is, is XOR enough to do so?
IMHO that's not enough because even combining (with XOR) an arbitrary numbers of limited keys (as the ones presented) then a bit of the plaintext may leak.
If my interpretation is correct I should first sum keys $\bmod 255$ and then XOR the result with the plaintext.
Generalising I need at least :
Ceil(message_space_size/key_space_size)

Keys
And should always sum them $\bmod 255$ to get the "composed" key.
At least this is my thoughts, but maybe I miss something, is it enough?
